# Click link under navigation bar in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the link under the navigation bar. I tried driver.findelement in this code snippet. It selects the link but the click event is not taking place.

```
WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']"));
         //WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.XPATH("Coplete_navigationbar_xpath")); List<WebElement> 
         List<WebElement>  allLinks = menu.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
         String MenuOptn="";
         for (WebElement w : allLinks)
         {
             MenuOptn=w.getText();
             if(MenuOptn.equalsIgnoreCase("TRACKING"))
             {
                // System.out.println("tracking");
                 w.click();
                 System.out.println("tracking");
                 break;
             }
System.out.print(w.getText());
         }
```

Comment: Please put dom xml for that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try click using javascript

```
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(locator);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. If explained Why it does not work with document.click method it would be helpful.

Comment: Selenium tries to mimic humans. What humans cannot do selenium shouldn't. Humans cannot click a link under navigation bar (because they can't see it) so is the click function.

Comment: In cases like these JavaScript comes for rescue.

Comment: @Aparna what are the locator, and "arguments[0].click();", ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below options:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[contains(., '<link_text>')]")).click();

or 
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[contains(., '<link_text>')]")),10,10).doubleClick().perform();
```

I hope it will be helpful