# click on next button :rseleniun

Tags: r, selenium

```html
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
require(RSelenium)

# open the remote driver
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "C:/temp"
                                 ,  browser.download.folderList = 2L
                                 , browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting     = FALSE
                                 , browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk =  "application/zip"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox",remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",port = 4445L,extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
# 
# go to the webpage
remDr$navigate("https://www.expedia.co.uk/Shanghai-Hotels-Fairmont-Peace-Hotel.h44282.Hotel-Information") 


#close popup window
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
closebt <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "modalCloseButton")
closebt$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)# just to see if the popup windows is closed

# create R objects from the website elements
guestreview <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = "tab-reviews")


# click the guest review button
guestreview$clickElement()

# Let us read the html page now and extract the links of the various articles loaded
#
# get the page html
#
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()

#load first 10 review
reviews <- read_html(page_source[[1]]) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "translate-text", " " ))]') %>% 
  html_text()
reviews
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

#load next page

Nextbtn <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "pagination-next", " " ))] | //abbr')
Nextbtn$clickElement()


remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
remDr$close()
```

Hi everyone. I need help to solve my problem. I want to click on button next to scrap more users review. But the problem is that I get this error message:

> Selenium message:Element is not clickable at point

There is no popup windows or alert and when I make a

> remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

I can see the button is there so it’s not hidden.
I’m using selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0 image
Can you please help me? I don’t know what I am doing wrong

Comment: anybody to help? suggestions? i'm still looking for an answer...

Answer (score 3):

```html
#load next page
#click on next
#remDr$findElement(using = 'class', "pagination-next")$clickElement() 

remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].click();"
                    , list(remDr$findElement("class", "pagination-next")))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

I finally find the error. There was a navbar covering the element that I wanted to click.
That’s why I was getting the error 
Element is not clickable due to another element that would receive the click
To solve this according to this link I used a JavaScript to click on the element. And bingo, it worked for me
[RSelenium and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109267/rselenium-and-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628069/click-link-under-navigation-bar-in-selenium-webdriver/43631483#43631483